# Polymorphic deserialization jackson

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am trying to implement polymorphic deserialization in jackson and trying to make the same model work in two places.

I have ShopData object

```
public class ShopData extends Embeddable implements Serializable
{
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String logoImageUrl;
    private final String heroImageUrl;

    public ShopData(@JsonProperty(value = "id", required = true) int id,
                    @JsonProperty(value = "name", required = true) String name,
                    @JsonProperty(value = "logoImageUrl", required = true) String logoImageUrl,
                    @JsonProperty(value = "heroImageUrl", required = true) String heroImageUrl)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.logoImageUrl = logoImageUrl;
        this.heroImageUrl = heroImageUrl;
    }
}
```

My Embeddable object looks like this

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)

@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AnotherObject.class, name = "AnotherObject"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ShopData.class, name = "shop")
})

public abstract class Embeddable
{

}
```

I am trying to make this model work in two places. This model works as expected.

```
public Order(@JsonProperty(value = "_embedded", required = true) Embeddable embedded)
{
    this.embedded = (ShopData) embedded;
}

      "_embedded": {
        "shop": {
              "id": 1,
               "name": "",
               "freshItems": 5,
               "logoImageUrl": "",
               "heroImageUrl": "",
               "_links": {
                 "self": {
                    "href": "/shops/1"
                  }
         }
        }
```

While this doesn't

```
public ShopList(@JsonProperty(value = "entries", required = true) List<ShopData> entries)
{
    this.entries = Collections.unmodifiableList(entries);
}


{
  "entries": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "",
      "freshItems": 5,
      "logoImageUrl": "",
      "heroImageUrl": "",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/shops/1"
        }
      }
    }
   ]
}
```

And throws error :`Could not resolve type id 'id' into a subtype`

I understand the error but do not know how to resolve this. I would like to be able to use the same model in both cases. Is this possible?

Comment: I think the problem is that ShopData list wants such json: `[{"shop": {...}}, {"shop": {...}}, {"shop": {...}}]` because `ShopData` inherents `Embeddable` behavior `@JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)`

Comment: Yes I know... But I wish to find a way to simply use the same model in both situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the answer myself. Should have simply added this anotation

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
public class ShopData extends Embeddable implements Serializable
```